# NSString stringWithFormat causing iPhone app to crash

Tags: iphone, crash

When I construct a dynamic URL using NSString stringWithFormat and then use that value in my XML parser I get random crashes. However if I test it with a constant string it works fine...

This is my code for generating the string,

```
loginURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ScriptURLString,@"authenticate"];
```

Which results in,

```
http://edms.digistorm.com.au/test/index.php?s=&sc=D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E&m=authenticate
```

Then I use it in my XML parser,

```
XMLReturnData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
xml = [[XMLParser alloc] 
       initWithXMLPath:loginURL 
       lookForElement:@"Authenticate" 
       setCallbackObject:self 
       withSelector:@selector(dataReady) 
       data:XMLReturnData
       ];
```

For some reason this is causing my app to crash. If I use a constant string like,

```
loginURL = @"http://edms.digistorm.com.au/test/index.php?s=&sc=D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E&m=authenticate";
```

it works fine...

loginURL is defined as NSString *loginURL; inside my header file for this view.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Can your give us the error it gives? If possible copy the stacktrace from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows your string is get released and when you calls it in XML parser it crashes the app.

actually `stringWithForma`t gives a `autorelease` object for string.

So what you need,make your string as retain property inside .h then synthesize it in .m and release it in dealloc method.

and also do this,

in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSString *tempString=[[NSString alloc] init];  //using this because your string is retain type so it prevent increment in retain count.
self.loginURL=tempString;
[tempString release];
```

Now when you use `stringWithFormat` use like this

```
self.loginURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ScriptURLString,@"authenticate"] retain];
```

It solves your problem.

Comment: it is also wrong. tempString is ok, but every time using retain without releasing, it gives memoey leak. And you haven't define how did you make your loginURL property. It is (retain) or (assign). If it is (retain), you should use `self.loginURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ScriptURLString,@"authenticate"];`. Without retain and with self. Also you can use the technique like in tempString with `[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@",ScriptURLString,@"authenticate"];`

Comment: @Alkimake, I already mention make property retain if you carefully read and also you need to retain it when you use a function which make your object autorealease.Using self before property is good point i change that(i always use self with property but when you alloc the property then it is must otherwise you can use without self.)

Comment: i misread, sorry. By the way if you alloc, you can use self. But you have to release again. It is good way to be sure that existing object will release before assignment, and after assignment retainCount will be 2. and you release again. It is known method for memory management.

Comment: Thanks @Ishu (and everyone else who commented), as you said, that did fix it for me, I really appreciate the help guys!

Answer (score 4):

The method you are using to allocate the string is important.

You have two basic ways to allocate your string:

```
NSString *loginURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@authenticate", ScriptURLString];
```

Compared to:

```
NSString *loginURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@authenticate", ScriptURLString];
```

For the first, Cocoa conventions say that because you caused the object to be created via an alloc message you "own" it and are responsible for releasing it.

For the latter, the convention is that because you caused the object to be created by a class "convenience" method, you do NOT own it and are not responsible for releasing it. The class (here, NSString) has that responsibility which it will discharge through an autorelease pool.

To summarise, when you explicitly create something with an alloc/init, you must release it. When you use a `[NSThing thingWithXXX]` style method you must not.

Comment: you are wrong that you said constant string is equivalent to `NSString *loginURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@authenticate", ScriptURLString];`. Contant strings handled by and added to autorelease pool. If you allocate the string, it is your responsibility to release it. But for constant string, you must not release. And second method creates a string that is owned by NSString class, which also puts it in the auto release pool. So constant strings are more likely the string with created buy NSString static methods.

Comment: @Alkimake quite right, have fixed it. My point was really just to clarify when he should and should not be calling release as without the whole code we can't be sure what he's doing and it sounds like he's releasing when he shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might help you.

```
loginURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@authenticate",ScriptURLString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to call `release` on `loginURL`, because you have'nt alloced it and only iOS have  right to destroy it...

Use below code

```
loginURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",ScriptURLString,@"authenticate"];
```

Once you used `loginURL` Do'nt forget to call `release` on it ...

```
   [loginURL release];
```